# Events from inside a DataBound Control

Tags: asp.net, events, controls, databound

I have an asp:Repeater with an asp:DropDownList in it.  The DropDownLists in the repeater raise their SelectedIndexChanged events on every postback, regardless of whether they were changed or not.

Is this a known issue in ASP.NET?  Do you know how to work around it?

I found [this workaround](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet.webcontrols/browse_thread/thread/d49fef3d6718fc6d?pli=1) but would like something prettier if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I found it - I was adding the event handler in codebehind, but when I moved it to the OnSelectedIndexChanged attribute of the asp:DropDownList control in the ASP.NET markup everything started behaving correctly.